# Join same table twice on same column with different value returning most recent row only

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm stuck trying to solve a small part of what is otherwise a complex JOIN.

We have an 'instructions' table and an 'estimates' table. In the 'estimates' we have multiple rows for different types of estimates for a given instruction.

Instructions Table

```
id | address | status
1 | 27 TAYLOR ROAD, ALBION PARK NSW 2527 | InProgress
```

Estimates Table

```
id | instruction_id | basis | basis_date | basis_value  
1 | 1 | ContractPrice | 2012-04-05 | 124000  
2 | 1 | CAMV | 2012-02-01 | 120000  
3 | 1 | CustomerEstimate | 2012-06-07 | 132000  
4 | 1 | ContractPrice | 2013-01-03 | 140000  
5 | 1 | CustomerEstimate | 2013-02-09 | 145000
```

What we want is actually 2 joins of 'instructions' on 'estimates' based on instructions.id = estimates.instruction_id and estimates.basis for 1) the most recent 'CustomerEstimate' (aliasing basis_date and basis_value as estimate_date and estimate_value) and 2) most recent 'ContractPrice' (again, aliasing basis_date and basis_value as contact_date and contract_value).

The intended result would be as follows;

```
id | address | status | contract_price | contract_date | estimate_date | estimate_value  
1 | 27 TAYLOR ROAD, ALBION PARK NSW 2527 | InProgress | 2013-01-03 | 140000 | 2013-02-09 | 145000
```

I would really appreciate some assistance from the SQL gurus out there.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Since this isn't just a code writing service, what did you do already?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT i.id, i.address, i.status, 
        co.basis_value As contract_price, 
        co.basis_date  As contract_date,
        es.basis_date  As estimate_date, 
        es.basis_value As estimate_value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By i.id Order By co.basis_date, es.basis_date) As RN
    FROM       instructions As i
    INNER JOIN estimates As co  ON (i.id = co.instruction_id AND co.basis = 'ContractPrice')
    INNER JOIN estimates As es  ON (i.id = es.instruction_id AND es.basis = 'CustomerEstimate')
) As a
WHERE RN = 1
```